# Sum radio button show/hide certain div based in the sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am new to javascript and html I am trying to sum my radio that been selected with same class and show certain div based in the total I am calling my function onclick of every radio however its not working not showing or hiding div

I cannot use document ready can i do it by onclick ?

```js
function calcscore() {
  $('.aa').css('display', 'none');
  $('.bb').css('display', 'none');
  var score = 0;
  $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
    score += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $("#totalScore").text(score);
  if (score < 3) {
    $('.bb').css('display', 'none');
    $('.aa').css('display', 'block');

  } else if (score > 2) {
    $('.bb').css('display', 'block');
    $('.aa').css('display', 'none');
  }
}

function displayRadioValue() {
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    calcscore()
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-top:20px;width:98%;" border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:180px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="tptx"> test1
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick=" displayRadioValue()" class="calc" value="0" type="radio" name="P1">&nbsp; 0
      </td>

      <td class="tptCc">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" class="calc" value="1" type="radio" name="P1">&nbsp; 1
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick=" displayRadioValue()" class="calc" value="2" type="radio" name="P1">&nbsp; 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tptx">test2
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" type="radio" class="calc" value="0" name="P11">&nbsp; 0
      </td>


      <td class="tptCc">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" type="radio" class="calc" value="1" name="P11">&nbsp; 1
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" type="radio" class="calc" value="2" name="P11">&nbsp; 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tptx">test3
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" class="calc" value="0" type="radio" name="P12">&nbsp; 0
      </td>

      <td class="tptCc">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" v="" type="radio" class="calc" value="1" name="P12">&nbsp; 1
      </td>

      <td class="tptCcS">
        <input onclick="displayRadioValue()" class="calc" value="2" type="radio" name="P12">&nbsp; 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="aa" style="display:none">
  show aa
</div>
<div class="bb" style="display:none">
  show aa
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Why can't you use document.ready? Also I recommend you attache the event handlers using jQuery instead of inline. Also look at .toggle

Comment: jQuery `.change()` is an event handler. It's supposed to be called whenever an event takes place (the change event in this case). Putting that inside a function just makes you setup the event handler over and over again instead of actually having it do something. Or I must be terribly wrong here..

Answer (score 1):

You already have the onchange, so no need to have inline onclick

In this case it is doubly wrong since you added the event handler wvery time you clicked, over and over again. Also

- a missing radio due to missing space in the declaration
- the same content in aa and bb
- a missing totalScore

I changed the inline style to CSS too

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    var score = 0;
    $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
      score += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#totalScore").text(score);
    $('.bb').toggle(score >= 3);
    $('.aa').toggle(score < 3);

  });
});
```

```css
.testTable {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 98%;
  border: 1px outset grey;
  padding: 1px
}

.testTable td {
  border: thin inset grey;
  margin: 1;
}

input.calc { margin-right:1em;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="testTable">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:180px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
    <col style="width:120px">
    <col style="width:60px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tptx"> test1</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input class="calc" value="0" type="radio" name="P1">0</td>
      <td class="tptCc"><input class="calc" value="1" type="radio" name="P1">1</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input class="calc" value="2" type="radio" name="P1">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tptx">test2</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input type="radio" class="calc" value="0" name="P11">0</td>
      <td class="tptCc"><input type="radio" class="calc" value="1" name="P11">1</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input type="radio" class="calc" value="2" name="P11">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tptx">test3</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input class="calc" value="0" type="radio" name="P12">0</td>
      <td class="tptCc"><input type="radio" class="calc" value="1" name="P12">1</td>
      <td class="tptCcS"><input class="calc" value="2" type="radio" name="P12">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<span id="totalScore"></span>
<div class="aa" style="display:none">show aa</div>
<div class="bb" style="display:none">show bb</div>
```

Comment: Might want to at least change up the html from `show aa` twice to just once and `show bb` in the other. Otherwise it looks like it's still not working as supposed to, haha. Could've fooled me